# Retrieve asset thumbnails list SFMC REST API

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, content-assets

I'm aware of /asset/v1/assets/{id}/thumbnail endpoint
But my question  - is it possible to provide somehow set of ids instead of a single value
Or maybe there is some documentation to check it out?

Comment: maybe there is another endpoint that supports POST?

Answer (score 1):

There's a REST endpoint for [retrieving all assets with a filter](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/assetAdvancedQuery.html).  You can build a query around it.  Something like this one I use to get email related [assetTypes](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/base-asset-types.html) :

```
POST /asset/v1/content/assets/query HTTP/1.1
Host: {{et_subdomain}}.rest.marketingcloudapis.com
Content-Type: application/json

{
      "page": {
        "page": 1,
        "pageSize": 10
      },
      "query": {
           "property": "assetType.id",
            "simpleOperator": "IN",
            "value": [3,4,5,6,195,196,197,198,199,200,201,202,203,207,208,209,210,211,212,213,214]
      },
      "sort": [
         {
            "property": "category.parentId",
            "direction": "ASC"
          },
          {
            "property": "category.id",
            "direction": "ASC"
          },
          {
            "property": "name",
            "direction": "ASC"
          }
      ]
    }
```

Comment: it's great but the question was about getting thumbnails (not step by step but the whole set using one call)

Comment: There's no route for retrieving thumbnails for a set of IDs.  The above will get you all of the IDs as preparation for retrieving the thumbnails.

Comment: yeap, thanks. in that case we have only two solutions: invoke all the `restEndpoints` and use `publishedURL` instead